# PermissionError: [Errno 13] while writing to a text file with python and reading it with UE4

Tags: python, opencv, unreal-engine4

I'm working on a project in python 3.7 and unreal engine 4. The python code uses an openCV library to track position of an object from a camera footage, by finding contours and marking the center point of the contour. Then the center point coordinates are converted to a String and written to a text file. UE4 then reads the file and prints the String(for now). Everything happens at runtime, as I want the position to be tracked in real time.

Now this solution works... for a moment. When I run the python code(I use PyCharm as an IDE) and unreal engine 4, it works for a short period of time(10 to 30 seconds at best) as the string is being printed in the game, but then the python script returns a permission error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Purs/PycharmProjects/opencv-python/capture1.py", line 53, in <module>
    findColor(img, myColors)
  File "C:/Users/Purs/PycharmProjects/opencv-python/capture1.py", line 26, in findColor
    x,y = getCountours(mask)
  File "C:/Users/Purs/PycharmProjects/opencv-python/capture1.py", line 42, in getCountours
    logistics(s)
  File "C:/Users/Purs/PycharmProjects/opencv-python/capture1.py", line 47, in logistics
    with open(dir, "w") as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\\\Users\\\\Purs\\\\Documents\\\\Unreal Projects\\\\TextFileTest\\\\WindowsNoEditor\\\\TextFileTest\\\\Content\\\\Files\\\\data.txt'
```

This is the python code I'm using to capture footage, find the center point and write to the text file.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

dir = r"C:\\Users\\Purs\\Documents\\Unreal Projects\\TextFileTest\\WindowsNoEditor\\TextFileTest\\Content\\Files\\data.txt"

frameWidth = 640
frameHeight = 480
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, frameWidth)
cap.set(4, frameHeight)
cap.set(10, 150)

myColors = [[0,0,255,0,0,255]]
myData = []
s = []

def findColor(img,myColors):
    imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    for color in myColors:
        lower = np.array(color[0:3])
        upper = np.array(color[3:6])
        mask = cv2.inRange(imgHSV,lower,upper)
        x,y = getCountours(mask)
        cv2.circle(imgResult,(x,y),3,(255,0,0),cv2.FILLED)

def getCountours(img):
    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    x,y,w,h = 0,0,0,0
    for cnt in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        if area>500:
            cv2.drawContours(imgResult, cnt, -1, (255,0,0), 3)
            peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.02*peri,True)
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
            myData = [x, y]
            s = str(myData)[1:-1]
            logistics(s)

    return x+w//2, y+h//2

def logistics(s):
    with open(dir, "w") as f:
        f.write(s)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    imgResult = img.copy()
    findColor(img, myColors)

    cv2.imshow("Result", imgResult)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

I tried this in UE4 editor and in a packaged game, but the results seem to be the same. All users should have permission to access the text file, and I have run PyCharm as administrator.

As you might have already notice I'm a beginner and I won't be surprised if this solution is a dead end. So if this is not salvageable I would be very grateful if somebody could point me in the right direction, when it comes to passing data from a python (or C++ as I think I should be able to recreate the python code in VS) to Unreal.

Thank you, and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

you're using too many backslashes. this is a pure python issue. all the other libraries are irrelevant to the issue.

python has "r-strings", strings prefixed with an `r`, like `r"example\with\backslashes and you can't have control characters in here"`. in those, a backslash is taken literally, so you don't escape it with another backslash.

if you use a normal string, you would have to escape a backslash. the backslash in a normal string escapes control characters such as newlines. example: `"example\nwith\nnewlines and here's a backslash: \\"`.

you can either remove the `r` from the path string, or remove all the escaping-backslashes from the path-backslashes

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation. I tried the two approaches you've proposed, but unfortunately the error still occurs. I have tried to set the path as:

`r"C:\Users\Purs\Documents\Unreal Projects\TextFileTest\WindowsNoEditor\TextFileTest\Content\Files\data.txt" `
or `"C:\\Users\\Purs\\Documents\\Unreal Projects\\TextFileTest\\WindowsNoEditor\\TextFileTest\\Content\\Files\\data.txt"`

The code seems to be a little more stable, lasting a while longer but the error mentioned in the main post still occurs. I have tried to use 'pathlib' but the result is still the same.

Comment: you are overwriting that file potentially multiple times per picture. you might not want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

So I have tried to follow the advice from Christoph Rackwitz and decrease the frequency of writes, by decreasing the number of captured frames, as this code makes a write every time a frame is captured. This did not work, and the issue persisted. It probably was a wrong way to go from the beginning, as writing and reading a file simultaneously even with significant delays returned the above error.

However, I found a solution to my issue. I used sockets, making the Python code act as a local "server" and UE4 as a client. Python can use Sockets from the get go, while Unreal needs a plugin. Fortunately, there is a simple plugin for UE4 that can be obtained from the marketplace, which in turn makes it easy to install on all of the recent engine iterations. As for now, the result is great and enough for me to keep prototyping my project.

So if anybody wants an easy communication between a Python code and UE4, its something I can recommend. At least for small operations like mine.